# Getting Id of Ribbon Button In CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I created one javascript in which i want to hide ribbon `Reactivate Lead` button depending  on some condition.

I got the Id of the button by pressing F12 on form which is `lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ReactivateLead-Large` .

In jscript , to get that button -

```
document.getElementById("lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ReactivateLead-Large");
```

but I am not getting that button, its giving me null .. I am not getting what is the problem . please let me know if anybody has suggetions.

thanks

Comment: crm-2011 The ribbon button cannot be hidden using Jscript. Try this instead http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/06/17/crm-2011-enabling-and-disabling-ribbon-buttons-2/

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you retrieve a null value is because the ribbon menu is displayed asynchronously. So if you try to retrieve the button when the onload event of the form is triggered, the button won't necessarily be in the DOM already.

The link provided by Luke will show you the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, but you might need to hold your nose whilst using it

```
function HideARibbonButton(nameOfButton) {
    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.top.document.getElementById(nameOfButton) != null) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);

            //top menu has loaded
            window.top.document.getElementById(nameOfButton).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Good answer but: There is a missing "}" at the end. "fuction" should be "function".

Comment: Excellent brute-force solution, I think this might really help out in a pinch. A supported alternative, buried in MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2013/crm.6/gg309322(v=crm.6)

Answer (score 2):

You can hide buttons in CRM2011 by altering the Entity customization XML.

Have a look at this:
http://gtcrm.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/hiding-a-ribbon-button-in-crm-2011/

Answer (score 1):

I also found that if you don't use `window.top` before `document..` it doesn't always work.

My code always starts with `window.top.document` etc..

see below:

```
tabSave = window.top.document.getElementById("salesorder|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.salesorder.MainTab.Save");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because the ribbon takes some time to display so you have to set an interval (code to be executed every 2 second for example) in which you place your code which will hide the button.

Or, you can  display rule which control the visibility of the button depending on the Boolean value returned by a java script function