# Dynamics: how to modify Ribbon using Web Resource JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Update:

By binding the function to a different event, I established that the reason is indeed that the Ribbon loads at its own time.

[It is possible to query the DOM until the Ribbon loads, and then make the button invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7914632), but this is highly discouraged. I've posted an answer below with a better, supported default alternative.

---

On Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I'm tasked to make a Ribbon button invisible using JavaScript. The code is to be implemented as a web resource on the relevant Form.

From the browser console, starting inside the form frame (because the Ribbon is, I think, in a different frame)

```
parent.document.getElementById("myElementId").style.display = 'none';
```

works fine.

In the JavaScript web resource, along the MS [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/walkthrough-write-your-first-client-script), I've tried variations of:

```
var Example = window.Example || {};
(function () {
    this.formOnLoad = function () {
        top.document.getElementById("myElementId").style.display = 'none';
        // parent.document.getElementById("myElementId").style.display = 'none';
        // window.parent.document.getElementById("myElementId").style.display = 'none';
    }
}).call(Example);
```

but this throws a Script Error: `[...] Type Error: cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at Object.formOnLoad`.

- So am I not reaching the right frame?
- Or is the Ribbon not loading on time (I guess the Form OnLoad event is not connected to the Ribbon loading)?
- Or is it not possible to call `document.getElementById` from the Form for another frame?

**How can I modify the properties of the Ribbon elements from the Form Web Resource JavaScript?**

Answer (score 1):

As many before have said, DOM navigation is unsupported.

[It is possible to query the DOM until the Ribbon loads, and then make the button invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7914632/2143578), but this is highly discouraged.

A better, supported default alternative:

Export the entity as a solution, unzip, and in the customizations.xml add a HideCustomAction with location set to the button ID, then import that solution back:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2013/crm.6/gg309322(v=crm.6)

Comment: Isn't it easier to use the Ribbon Workbench tool for it? https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102796-5-hiding-unhiding-ribbon-elements